# What is Hybrid shut down in Windows Operating System and why it didn't effect in windows8.1 for the shutdown issue?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, shutdown

I had a problem with Windows 10 shutting down so I checked the [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/windows-10-wont-shut-down/633e1771-1737-4e90-af2d-62b0ab0618ff) ,there I tried the solution of turning off fast start-up/disabling hybrid shutdown and it worked.

As this was Introduced in Windows 8.1 ,before migrating to Windows 10 there wasn't any problem unlike now after the Migration.So why did this not cause any problem in earlier windows 8.1 was this option disabled by default or it had some other settings.

Also what exactly is Hybrid shutdown and in which scenario is this useful

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid shutdown/Fast startup decreases the total startup time by hibernating the kernel session instead of closing it to a file called hiberfil.sys upon shutdown, so when you boot your PC again it reads the information needed from the file instead of initializing it again from the start, which reduces the overall Windows loading time.

Hybrid shutdown is enabled by default on Windows 8 / 8.1 and also Windows 10, so I can't be sure why migrating to Windows 10 made it problematic for your setup.

See the following image for reference:
[image: Image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

**What is hibernation mode ?**

Hibernation is a power-saving mode that saves the system state to the hard drive and then shuts down the computer.

**What is hybrid shutdown ?**

According to this [page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/), hybrid shutdown uses a combination of hibernation and shutdown, so when you click *Shut down*, Windows *partially hibernates* and *partially shuts down*. When you power ON the computer, Windows will partially boot up and partially wake up, so it will start much faster.

**Was this option disabed by default in Windows 8 / 8.1 ?**

By default, in Windows 8 / 8.1, this option was **enabled** and is also default in Windows 10.